# Selenium Find Element by class name

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, classname

I would scrape from this page goals and red cards of each team. This is the url: https://www.flashscore.com/match/6DavxcEF/#match-summary

I tried by using this part of code

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='summary-content']/div[1]")
    goals=driver.find_element_by_class_name("icon soccer-ball").text
    card1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("icon yr-card").text
    card2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("icon r-card").text
 except NoSuchElementException:
    goals = " "
    card1 = " "
    card2 = " "
```

Anyone could help me?
Thanks

Comment: can you post expected/obtained output and/or any tracebacks? the question isn't clear, because we don't know the problem

Comment: you should use the ```requests``` module to scrape data from sites.

Comment: @LeonardoScotti I edited the code and I have blank result as return, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

When I examine the elements, the inside of the span tags in the icon y-card class name is empty. I solved the problem as follows.

```
md = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("detailMS__incidentRow")

for i in md:
    if i.find_elements_by_class_name("icon.y-card"):
        print(i.text)
```

In this way, the cards etc. You can access your data. With the `incidentRow-away` or `incidentRow-home` class names, you can only access the home or away team data. Be careful, you should use `find_elements`, not `find_element`, since there will be more than one data in tags in such selections.

In the example I have given, you can only access yellow card data. Finally, when you specify more than one class name, put a dot(.) Between them.

Comment: Great it works, I would append minute of those elements in each columns. It is possible?

Comment: You can find it from the class name of the span tag where the minute is located. ```i.find_element_by_class_name("time-box-wide")```. i'm didin't try this but i hope its work :)